# run lenght encode symbols in list

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to ask you for help to solve my task with printing of result of code below. Input is: `(run-length-encode '(1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 a a b b))` and it returns `((2 . 1) (2 . 2) (2 . 3) (2 . 4))` but i would like to have output like `(2 1 2 2 2 3 2 4 2 a 1 b)`. What i am doing wrong?

```
    (define (run-length-encode lst)
  (define (rle val-lst cur-val cur-cnt acc)
    (if (pair? val-lst)
        (let ((new-val (car val-lst)))
          (if (eq? new-val cur-val)
              (rle (cdr val-lst) cur-val (+ cur-cnt 1) acc)
              (rle (cdr val-lst) new-val 1 (cons (cons cur-cnt cur-val) acc))))
        (cons (cons cur-cnt cur-val) acc)))
         (if (pair? lst)
           (reverse (rle (cdr lst) (car lst) 1 '()))
           '()))
```

Thank you for help,
Jan

Comment: `(cons (cons cur-cnt cur-val) acc)` -> `(list* cur-val cur-cnt acc)`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. How easy :)